# Not operation with async pipes in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using Angular 4 as a front-end to build an app with Node JS as the back end. The front end will fetch data from a SQL database and display a form. Since, this fetch may take some time when deployed, I wanted to put a "Please wait" message while the data is fetched. For now I used async pipes, subjects and observables and a simple timeout function to test it works. I tried this code.

In .ts file:

```
dataReady = new Subject<any>();
dataReadyObs = new Observable<any>();

constructor() {
  this.dataReadyObs = this.dataReady.asObservable();
}

ngOnInit() {
    someFunc() {
       setTimeout(function() {
       this.dataReady.next(true);
       }.bind(this), 2000);
    }
}
```

In the html file:

```
<form *ngIf="dataReadyObs | async">

</form>

<h3 *ngIf="!dataReadyObs | async"> Please wait ... </h3>
```

But the "Please wait" message never shows up, only the form after 2 seconds. Is the ! operator not applicable when using pipes? I managed to solve this with ng-template, but in case the not operator is necessary, is there a way to use it with pipes?

```
<div *ngIf="dataReadyObs | async; else waitmessage">
  <form>

  </form>
</div>

<ng-template #waitmessage>
  <h3>Please wait ...</h3>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Edited the code

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use with pipes.To make it work you need to write like this with (). cause pipe is 2 operation so for angular its 'false | async'

```
<h3 *ngIf="!(dataReadyObs | async)"> Please wait ... </h3>
```

another approach is to use this is more safely

```
<h3 *ngIf="(dataReadyObs | async) === false"> Please wait ... </h3>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why BehaviorSubject would fix the problem ?

Comment: I am trying to use it with component, but the component's ngOnInit called without waiting the observable emit

Comment: This is not a recommended approach as observables often emit empty values on subscription, unless filtered, which can cause the ngIf expression to falsely fire. See http://codelyzer.com/rules/template-no-negated-async. Use @Sergei Panfilov's answer below instead to safely check.

Answer (score 20):

The way how todo that is following:

```
<h3 *ngIf="(dataReadyObs | async) === false"> Please wait ... </h3>
```

Because `!(dataReadyObs | async)` will produce tslint error at least

See [the problem with negating async](http://codelyzer.com/rules/template-no-negated-async/)